# C# abstract, subclass, How to explain this result

Tags: c#, subclass, abstract

The question: there is two classes, A and B

```
public abstract class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
    public virtual void Fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Fun()");
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
    public new void Fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.Fun()");
    }

}
```

If run:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        A a = new B();
        a.Fun();
    }
```

the output is:

```
A
B
A.Fun()
```

How to explain this result, I know it has something to do with abstract and suclassing, but I don't know how to explain. Please help.

Comment: If you want to override the method, you might want to use the `override` keyword instead of `new`.

Comment: In case you are wondering about the "A" - the base classes constructor is called from `B`s in any case

Comment: @mikez - make this an answer and explain the differences between `new` and `override` a bit - will happily upvote it

Comment: @Carsten feel free to post an answer and get the points. I don't have time to write out a full answer.

Comment: @mikez - NP another already did

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to differentiate between `new` and `override`:

- `new`: This does **not** *override* or *touch* the inherited base method. The method in `B` marked as `new` is only called when you call it on an object of type `B` (e.g. `((B)a).Fun()`), but not when calling an instance of type `B` mapped to an object of type `A`. Can be used on any method (i.e. "hiding the base method").
- `override` does *touch* the inheritance and the base function is *really* overriden. `a.Func()` will call the method defined in `B`. Can only be used on base methods marked as `virtual`.